# multiple static IP address

Tags: networking, router, ip, ipv4

I am trying to setup 2 external static IP address through a Arris Modem/router bridged to 2 router so I could split pc network and server network. How would I go about setting it up properly/ if it is even possible.

I have 5 usable static from my ISP, setup with RIP, but every time I connect a router to the modem through bridge the rest of the ports are automatically disabled.

How could I divide my networks so my servers would have one static IP and my regular devices will have another.

Comment: the ports on the what are disabled? the bridge? the router?

Comment: the arris is a cable modem and a router. But its set to act as only a modem and is bridged to a stand alone router, as soon as i plug in a router into the arris cable modem LAN port. it disables all the other physical ports.

Comment: What i am trying to do is setup two networks with two dedicated IP from the external world. I am not sure about the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Arris FAQ](http://arris.force.com/consumers/articles/General_FAQs/Bridge-Mode-vs-Routed-Subnet/?l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle) what you're looking for is the 'Routed Subnet' mode.

[Bridge vs Routed Subnet mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVlv8.jpg)

A routed subnet allows you to utilize your static (public) IP addresses on devices that connect directly to the Motorola Gateway.

You can setup servers behind the Arris gateway by assigning them Public IPs.